# How to comput more than num_classes - 1 LDA directions in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn

I've been using [sklearn LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html) to compute LDA projection directions. But it only allows me to compute up to K-1 of them, where K is the number of classes the data belongs to.

How can I compute K or more directions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The between-class scatter matrix is of rank at most `n_classes - 1`, thus there are at most `n_classes - 1` directions that maximize the ratio of the between-class variance and the within- class variance.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Multiclass_LDA for more details.